# How do you change the title of a pdf using django?

Tags: python, django

So I have this app that allows you to upload pdfs then you can view them in the browser and it works fine but the only problem is that my title is a regex for some reason :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym2bR.png)

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
               path("show_file/r'^(?P<file_id>\d+)",v.show_file, name="show_file" ),
]
```

`views.py`

```
def show_file(response,file_id):
    doc = Document.objects.get(id=file_id)
    pdf = open(f"media/{doc.file}", 'rb')
    return FileResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

`models.py`

```py
class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=65, null=False, blank=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    grade = models.IntegerField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/")
    date_uploaded = models.DateField(null=False)
```

`forms.py`

```py
class DocumentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subject = forms.ChoiceField(choices=subject_choices)
    grade = forms.ChoiceField(choices=grade_choices)
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ("title","subject","grade","file","date_uploaded")
```

Comment: "my title is a regex for some reason"—please show the code that _creates_ the PDF. Opening it and returning it has nothing to do with this. See [ask].

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is showing the last segment of the URL in the absence of any other title. Just change your URL to

```
path("show_file/<file_id>", v.show_file, name="show_file"),
```

What you have now seems to be a half-baked porting of a regexp-based `re_path` to the `<>`-based `path`s.

Comment: Now its giving me the id but I think i can fix it. Thanks @AKX

Answer (score 0):

You just have to include the file title in the URL like so, but first pass it from your template.

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
     path("show_file/<file_id>/<file_title>",v.show_file, name="show_file" ),
            ]
```

like:

```
    <a href=
    "{% url 'show_file' file_id=file.id file_title=file.title %}"
    class="text-right">View</a>
```